# Pull list from Firebase based on set of Attributes

Tags: database, firebase

**Assumptions:** I have a database of about 1 million entries in Firebase. Every entry is structured the same. They have a creation date and 5 other boolean attributes: attribute A, B, C, D, E, and date.

**Question:** Can I return a list of the 20 most recent entries that have attribute A==true and D==false?

Can this be done? Will it go fast enough that a user won't be too annoyed by the search time (less than a few seconds)?

If Firebase can't do this, can I use some other service like BigQuery or Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase can't do that, you'd have to create a single key that word store all of them and then query once.

Recommendations for other services are not part of stackoverflow but you can look into algolia.

Comment: That is disappointing. I'm getting pretty close to getting BigQuery to work. I was hoping I could just use built-in Firebase features though.